# Group by month and year in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by, date

Given a table with a timestamp on each row, how would you format the query to fit into this specific json object format.

I am trying to organize a json object into years / months.

json to base the query off:

```
{
  "2009":["August","July","September"],
  "2010":["January", "February", "October"]
}
```

Here is the query I have so far -

```
SELECT
    MONTHNAME(t.summaryDateTime) as month, YEAR(t.summaryDateTime) as year
FROM
    trading_summary t 
GROUP BY MONTH(t.summaryDateTime) DESC";
```

The query is breaking down because it is (predictably) lumping together the different years.

Answer (score 253, accepted):

```
GROUP BY YEAR(t.summaryDateTime), MONTH(t.summaryDateTime);
```

is what you want.

Comment: +1: Another alternative using [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format): `DATE_FORMAT(t.summaryDateTime, '%Y-%m')`

Comment: Further on this, [FROM_UNIXTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) is needed if you have a UNIX timestamp in your DB `DATE_FORMAT( FROM_UNIXTIME(t.summaryDateTime), '%Y-%m' )`

Comment: Thanks @OMGPonies , with your syntax I'm able to perform conditional GROUP BY.

Comment: Performance... my test of `GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date) DESC;` (~450 ms) and `GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m')` (~850 ms) on a InnoDB table with > 300,000 entries showed the former (the marked answer to this question) took ~half the time as the latter.

Answer (score 103):

```
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(summaryDateTime,'%Y-%m')
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This is an old and already answered question. We'll be happy if you could contribute to more pressing questions too. You can  find tips on to provide good answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: See my comment on the answer above... On large-ish tables this method takes twice as long.

Answer (score 16):

I prefer

```
SELECT
    MONTHNAME(t.summaryDateTime) as month, YEAR(t.summaryDateTime) as year
FROM
    trading_summary t 
GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM t.summaryDateTime);
```

Answer (score 15):

I know this is an old question, but the following should work if you don't need the month name at the DB level:

```
  SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM summaryDateTime) summary_year_month 
    FROM trading_summary  
GROUP BY summary_year_month;
```

[See EXTRACT function docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract)

You will probably find this to be better performing.. and if you are building a JSON object in the application layer, you can do the formatting/ordering as you run through the results.

**N.B.** I wasn't aware you could add DESC to a GROUP BY clause in MySQL, perhaps you are missing an ORDER BY clause:

```
  SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM summaryDateTime) summary_year_month 
    FROM trading_summary  
GROUP BY summary_year_month
ORDER BY summary_year_month DESC;
```

Comment: please note that the output from `EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM summaryDateTime)` is `201901`

Comment: @EdgarOrtega Yep, but that should be enough to generate the desired JSON object in the original question using application logic. Assuming that some form of looping over the query result is already happening, my approach aims to get the minimum required information from the DB as simply and quickly as possible

Comment: You're right, that should be enough. My comment was only to indicate what the output from that function is like, maybe someone does not like that format.

Comment: @EdgarOrtega No worries, thanks, a worthy contribution!

Answer (score 10):

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(t.summaryDateTime) as month, YEAR(t.summaryDateTime) as year
FROM trading_summary t
GROUP BY YEAR(t.summaryDateTime) DESC, MONTH(t.summaryDateTime) DESC
```

**Should use DESC for both YEAR and Month to get correct order.**

Answer (score 4):

You must do something like this

```
SELECT onDay, id, 
sum(pxLow)/count(*),sum(pxLow),count(`*`),
CONCAT(YEAR(onDay),"-",MONTH(onDay)) as sdate 
FROM ... where stockParent_id =16120 group by sdate order by onDay
```

Answer (score 4):

This is how I do it:

```
GROUP BY  EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM t.summaryDateTime);
```

Answer (score 3):

use EXTRACT function like this

```
mysql> SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM '2009-07-02');
       -> 2009
```

Answer (score 3):

You cal also do this

```
SELECT  SUM(amnt) `value`,DATE_FORMAT(dtrg,'%m-%y') AS label FROM rentpay GROUP BY YEAR(dtrg) DESC, MONTH(dtrg) DESC LIMIT 12
```

to order by year and month. Lets say you want to order from this year and this month all the way back to 12 month

Answer (score 2):

You are grouping by month only, you have to add YEAR() to the group by

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT YEAR(t.summaryDateTime) as yr, GROUP_CONCAT(MONTHNAME(t.summaryDateTime)) AS month 
FROM trading_summary t GROUP BY yr
```

Still you would need to process it in external script to get exactly the structure you're looking for.

For example use PHP's explode to create an array from list of month names and then use json_encode()

Answer (score 0):

As this data is being pulled for a trade summary by month, I had to do the same thing and would just like to add the code I use. The data I have is saved in the database as a string so your query may be simpler. Either way, as a trader, this is in essence what most people would be looking for:

```
select
    DATE(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(closeDate, '%Y-%m-%d'), '%Y-%m-01')) AS month_beginning,
    COUNT(*) AS trades,
    TRUNCATE(sum(profitLoss)/count(*),2) as 'avgProfit',
    TRUNCATE(sum(percentGain)/count(*),2) as 'avgPercent',
    sum(profitLoss) as 'gi',
    sum(profitLoss > 0)/count(*) AS winPercent,
    sum(profitLoss < 0)/count(*) as 'lossPercent',
    max(profitLoss) as bigWinner,
    min(profitLoss) as bigLoser
from tradeHistory
group by month_beginning
order by month_beginning DESC
```

However, it will skip months that are missing in your data. So if there is no data for Jan, there won't be a row.

Answer (score -1):

I would like add difference between group by year(datetime),month(datetime) and groupb by extract(year_month from datetime).
here is the query i tried with these two cases.

select year(datetimecol) as Year,monthname(datetimecol) as Month from table
group by year(datetimecol) and month(datetimecol) order by year(datetimecol) desc;

result:

## Year, Month

2020, May

select year( datetimecol) as Year,monthname(datetimecol) as Month from table
GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM datetimecol) order by year(datetimecol) desc,month(datetimecol) asc;

result:

## Year, Month

2021, January
2021, February
2021, March
2021, April
2021, May
2020, May
2020, June
2020, July
2020, August
2020, September
2020, October
2020, November
2020, December

(this is the result i need)

My observation
1.when i am using with group by year(datetimecol),month(datetimecol) , not giving desired result ..might be because of datetime feild...
2.when i tired second query with GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM datetimecol) order by year(datetimecol)...its working absolutely fine.

in conclusion, for getting months by year wise use the following query.

select year( datetimecol) as Year,monthname(datetimecol) as Month from table
GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM datetimecol) order by year(datetimecol) desc,month(datetimecol) asc;

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29104370)

Comment: i tried this context and given my observation.i didnt give without tested.

Answer (score -3):

Use

```
GROUP BY year, month DESC";
```

Instead of

```
GROUP BY MONTH(t.summaryDateTime) DESC";
```

Comment: although it appears that GROUP BY MONTH(t.summaryDateTime) DESC doesn't order the months properly for some reason...