# How do I get a breakdown by the hour using a  single query in MySql?

Tags: mysql

Let's say my table looks like this:

```
Sessions
start_dts (datetime)
end_dts (datetime)
```

and the data looks like this:

```
start_dts             end_dts
12/25/2011 01:55:00   12/25/2011 03:30:00
```

I need the query results to look like this:

```
Date          Hour    MinutesOnline
12/25/2011    0       0
12/25/2011    1       5
12/25/2011    2       60
12/25/2011    3       30
... (every hour of the date range being queried)
```

Is this even possible with a single query?

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366895/group-by-month-and-year-in-mysql

Comment: @Matthew: the main issue here is to generate N rows using 2 dates as an input. And after generating the data will be ready to use without further group by's

Comment: @zerkms you're right, I misread the question.

Comment: good question. If I had mysql available, I'm intrigued enough to try and solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pretty good start.  This will work for any date/time range. However, it has one main prerequisite: You need to create an `intervals` table with a `dt_hr datetime` field which contains all the intervals you are scanning over.

```
Ex: '2011-12-25 00:00:00',
    '2011-12-25 01:00:00',
    '2011-12-25 02:00:00',
    '2011-12-25 03:00:00',
          . . .
    '2011-12-25 23:00:00'
```

-

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(intervals.dt_hr,'%m/%d/%Y') AS Date,
       EXTRACT(HOUR FROM intervals.dt_hr) AS Hour,
       CASE 
          WHEN intervals.dt_hr > TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR,HOUR(s2.start_dts), DATE(s2.start_dts)) 
               AND intervals.dt_hr < TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR,HOUR(s2.end_dts), DATE(s2.end_dts))
            THEN 60
          WHEN intervals.dt_hr = TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR,HOUR(s2.start_dts), DATE(s2.start_dts)) 
               AND intervals.dt_hr < TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR,HOUR(s2.end_dts), DATE(s2.end_dts))
            THEN 60 - EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM s2.start_dts)
          WHEN intervals.dt_hr = TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR,HOUR(s2.end_dts), DATE(s2.end_dts))
               AND intervals.dt_hr > TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR,HOUR(s2.start_dts), DATE(s2.start_dts)) 
            THEN EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM s2.end_dts)
          WHEN intervals.dt_hr = TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR,HOUR(s2.start_dts), DATE(s2.start_dts)) 
               AND intervals.dt_hr = TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR,HOUR(s2.end_dts), DATE(s2.end_dts))
            THEN EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM s2.end_dts) - EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM s2.start_dts)
          ELSE 0
       END AS MinutesOnLine
FROM intervals
LEFT JOIN sessions s2 
  ON intervals.dt_hr >= TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR,HOUR(s2.start_dts), DATE(s2.start_dts)) 
    AND intervals.dt_hr <= TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR,HOUR(s2.end_dts), DATE(s2.end_dts))
```

To generate the `intervals` table, you could create a stored procedure which creates a temporary table with a date_hour sequence.  See [Get a list of dates between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510012/get-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates) for a way to do this.

Comment: This looks fantastic.  I'll follow-up tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

More of a big comment than answer.

Not good enough with MySQL to do it but
a CTE to come up with a set of datetimes between start_dts and end_dts
so you get

```
startTime           endTime     
12/25/2011 01:00:00 12/25/2011 02:00:00
12/25/2011 02:00:00 12/25/2011 03:00:00
12/25/2011 03:00:00 12/25/2011 04:00:00
```

joined back to session On CT.EndTime < DateAdd(sessions.end_dts, INTERVAL 1 HOUR)

and then Hour(CTS.StartTime) - Hour(sessions.start_dts)
and modulus of the time difference in minutes beteen cte.endtime and start_dts

maybe...