# MySQL orders by category by month

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a table of orders with these columns: order_item  order_category order_date 
so the data looks like so:

```
order_item  order_category   order_date 
1235        hardware         2014-01-07
1349        bedding          2014-01-07
1636        hardware         2014-01-08
```

etc.

There are about 20 product categories. This query gets me how many items were ordered by category each day:

```
 SELECT order_date, count(order_item) as num, order_category  
 FROM orders
 GROUP BY order_date, order_category
```

I would like to get a result that shows month and the count for each category, so it would look like this:

```
 month    bedding  hardware etc
 2013-12  5        8
 2014-01  9        0
```

Can I do this with mysql?

Comment: `group by month(datefield)`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks basic research

Comment: The issue isn't aggregating by month, it is pivoting the categories.  With that hint, you should be able to google to a working solution within 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
   SELECT '2014-01' month , SUM(CASE WHEN order_category = 'hardware' 
                        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )as hardware, 
                            SUM(CASE WHEN order_category = 'bedding' 
                        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )as bedding
  FROM Table1
  WHERE MONTH(order_date) = 01 AND  year(order_date) = 2014

  UNION all 

  SELECT '2013-12' month , SUM(CASE WHEN order_category = 'hardware' 
                        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )as hardware, 
                           SUM(CASE WHEN order_category = 'bedding' 
                        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )as bedding
  FROM Table1
  WHERE MONTH(order_date) = 12 AND  year(order_date) = 2013
```

[**DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ace5c/1)

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. This is terrific and I did use varchar for the date as it happens - but I guess I cannot avoid naming every category in the query?

Answer (score 0):

You also have to group by year or you get the results for 'every january' of every year.

```
SELECT order_date, count(order_item) as num, order_category  
FROM orders
GROUP BY order_category, year(datefield), month(date field) desc;
```

a simple google for 'mysql group by year and month' gives this fine post...

[Group by month and year in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366895/group-by-month-and-year-in-mysql)

Comment: The OP is really asking for the results to be pivoted.