# PHP and SQL - How to select highest sum of all months in a current year?

Tags: php, mysql, select

So I have table 'item' in database with attributes: id, dateItem, price.

I want to find MAX(SUM(price)) for some month in a current year.

```
id  dateItem (Format: yyyy-mm-dd)    price
1   25.06.2015.                      986,69
2   21.06.2015.                      1564
3   22.03.2015.                      23,56
4   21.03.2015.                      187,23
5   01.03.2015.                      489,33
6   06.10.2015.                      975,26
```

I came up with something like this, but I know it's not ok. Please, help :s

```
$sql = "SELECT MAX(SUM(price)) FROM item WHERE DATE('Y') = 2015 AND 
dateItem between DATE('Y/m/1') and DATE('Y/m/31')";
```

Comment: Is that really the format of you date field (a string?) or is it really a `date` field type? So you want monthly sum and you want to find the highest of those?

Comment: You can just do `ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: What do you mean by `MAX(SUM())` when no `GROUP` is in use? you have only one `SUM` maximum among what?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group by month and year in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366895/group-by-month-and-year-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

You can't nest aggregation functions. You need to use a subquery.

```
SELECT MAX(pricesum) 
FROM (SELECT SUM(price) AS pricesum
      FROM item
      WHERE YEAR(dateItem) = YEAR(NOW())
      GROUP BY MONTH(dateItem)) AS subquery
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT SUM(price) AS pricesum
FROM item
WHERE YEAR(dateItem) = YEAR(NOW())
GROUP BY MONTH(dateItem)
ORDER BY pricesum DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

If you want to know the month as well, you can include that in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: :-)  Gordon, you are cheater! :-) :-D Very unexpectable solution to me :-)