# How to count items per month with a date attached to each one in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I want to count all new students in a given month from ten years ago to today and put that information into a table, separated month by month.

I have a mysql users table with the date the user enrolled in a timestamp format.

So, I've got something like this:
(the format is dd-mm-yyyy)

```
Unix --------------- readable date  
1528743811 --------- 11-6-2018  
1528740914 --------- 11-6-2018  
1528740347 --------- 11-6-2018  
1528733661 --------- 11-6-2018  
1528676301 --------- 10-5-2018  
1528657978 --------- 10-5-2018  
1528508065 --------- 8-5-2018   
1528492266 --------- 8-4-2018
etc..
```

How may I do the counting? (I would appreaciate even an idea of where to start, or how to actually formulate the problem, even in seudocode).

I expect something like this:

```
4-2018  --------- 1
5-2018  --------- 3
6-2018  --------- 4
```

> Please, if you think that the question **syntaxis can be improved** let me know,thanks! (english isn't my primary language).
>
> Also, If you want to **downvote**, or vote the question to be closed or
>   deleted, **please leave me a comment about why**, so I can improve my
>   questions. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried doing thus far? Please post your code attempts

Comment: Try to group by? something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366895/group-by-month-and-year-in-mysql

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Derek, I haven't done much, actually. I've sit down, got the dates from the database in a query, and started to think about how to actually arrive to the answer. I got stuck, that's why even seudocode will be appreciated, I'm not sure on how to start.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Isaac, that's actually a pretty good idea!!

Comment: Are you really storing both of those columns?

Comment: Post the real thing, your attempt sql code and the schema. That way you can improve the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do all this in SQL with `FROM_UNIXTIME()` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT 
    FROM_UNIXTIME([Unix], '%M %Y') AS Label, 
    COUNT(*) AS Count 
FROM [table] 
GROUP BY MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME([Unix])), YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME([Unix]))
WHERE ADDDATE(FROM_UNIXTIME([Unix]), INTERVAL 10 YEARS) >= CURDATE()
```

Or if that is too many `FROM_UNIXTIME`, you can subquery it.

Comment: `from ten years ago to today`