# Laravel groupBy month and sum the total

Tags: php, laravel

### Data Structure

```
[
{
  "id": "1",
  "date": "2019-06-22",
  "total": "1200" // THIS TOTAL IS A MUTATOR
},
{
  "id": "2",
  "date": "2019-06-24",
  "total": "2200" // THIS TOTAL IS A MUTATOR
},
{
  "id": "3",
  "date": "2019-07-20",
  "total": "2300" // THIS TOTAL IS A MUTATOR
},
]
```

### What I am trying to do:

I want to group these data by ***MONTH*** and return the sum

### Expected result:

`2019-06` total is `1200` AND `2019-07` total is `4500`

### What I have tried:

```
$customer_branch = ExportInvoice::where('customer_branch_id', $customer_branch_id)
            -> approved()
            -> whereYear('date', $year)
            -> orderBy('date', 'ASC')
            -> get();
```

And I have tried to loop throw `$customer_branch` and set data to array but I did not get the expected result

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366895/group-by-month-and-year-in-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Open `config/database.php`

2.Find **`strict`** key inside **mysql connection setting**s

3.Set the value to **`false`**

4.Then Run `php artisan config:cache`

**Now Try this Query**

```
ExportInvoice::select('id',\DB::raw('SUM(total) as total,DATE_FORMAT(date,"%Y-%m") as monthDate'))
->where('customer_branch_id', $customer_branch_id)
->approved()
->groupBy(\DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(date,"%Y-%m")'))
->orderBy('date')
->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

A simble DB:raw within a groupBy should do the trick.

```
$customer_branch = ExportInvoice::where('customer_branch_id', $customer_branch_id)
   ->approved()
   ->whereYear('date', $year)
   ->groupBy(DB::raw(DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m'))
   ->get();
```